# JSON/Python - decoding

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb, reformat, pyvmomi

I've got json formatted file, 'datastores.json' that looks like this:

```
{
"{'ESXi_Host': 'elvis.lab.vsphere.com'}": {
    "elvis.data": {
        "capacity": 293131517952, 
            "uuid": "57431578-630f1322-7bf2-00212883a5b0", 
            "vmfs_version": "5.60", 
            "ssd": false, 
            "extents": [
                "mpx.vmhba1:C0:T1:L0"
            ], 
            "local": true
```

I am running the following code on it:

```
import json

with open("C:\PyVmomi_out\\datastores.json") as json_file:
datastores = json.loads(json_file.read())
for dstor in datastores:
    esx_host = dstor['ESXi_Host']
    datastore = dstor['datastore']
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

On this line:

```
esx_host = dstor['ESXi_Host']
```

I understand that it is expecting an integer. From the reading I had been doing I though if I subbed in

```
'json.loads'
```

instead of

```
'json.load'
```

and also subbed in

```
'(json_file.read())'
```

instead of

```
'(json_file)'
```

then it would read the file in as string and allow string parsing instead of integers. Why didn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is you do not have "ESXi_Host" key in your .json, it says

```
"{'ESXi_Host': 'elvis.lab.vsphere.com'}"
```

notice `"` `"` around it, the key is `"{'ESXi_Host': 'elvis.lab.vsphere.com'}"` (this is a single string).

Second, loaded object will be probably a **dictionary**, thus iteration of form

```
for dstor in datastors:
```

is over **keys** (and keys are strings, which have only **integer indexes**), not values, to access values do something like

```
for _, dstor in datastors.iteritems():
```

Print your `datastores` and investigate what is the exact structure of your parsed .json.

Comment: I did not realize the single string would be a problem. The error msg mentions "integers", confusing. I am struggling to figure out how to fix the formatting so that the two strings are indeed split . The script for pulling the ESXi hosts/datastores in json format makes the host/datastore name the primary key. For dynamoDB I need them to have label of "ESXi_Host" and "datastore" as primary key and the corresponding names as the key-values. This is proving to be more difficult than I thought. I'll go back to the script that pulls the data from vsphere and keep trying to modify it. Thanks again!

Comment: Error regarding integers comes from the wrong iteration. You iterate over keys, keys are strings, and string have only integer indexes.